# Completeness of function space with uniform metric

Tags: general-topology

Let $A$ be a non empty set and let $(X , d)$ be a metric space. I know that the set of all functions from $A$ into $X$, endowed with the uniform metric is complete if $(X , d)$ is complete. But what can we say about the converse, that is if $(X , d)$ is not complete then is it true that the mentioned function space is not complete. If it is true then how to prove and if not can we have a counter example. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot define the uniform metric on this space if you consider all functions from $A$ to $X$. You have to restrict yourself to bounded functions. If you do this then converse is true. Given any Cauchy sequence $(x_n)$ in $X$ which is not convergent define $f_n: A \to X$ by $f_n(a)=x_n$ and $f_n (b)= y$ for  $b \neq a$ where $a \in A$ and $y \in X$ are fixed elements. Then $(f_n)$ is Cauchy but not convergent in the uniform metric.

Comment: One can define the uniform metric on the space of all functions if the metric is bounded. .

Comment: Sure, but  OP cannot assume that the metric is bounded unless that is specified.

Comment: Yes, and your second sentence "You have to restrict yourself to bounded functions" is correct for all metrics.

Comment: Yes we can define uniform metric on set of all functions from A into (X , d) via standard bounded metric corresponding to the metric d on X. See the definition of uniform metric given in page 266 in the book " Topology " by James R. Munkres. Also see the Theorem 43.5 in the same book.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If $\langle X,d\rangle$ is not complete, let $\langle x_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ be a Cauchy sequence in $X$ that does not converge. For each $n\in\Bbb N$ let $f_n:A\to X:a\mapsto x_n$, so that $f_n$ is the constant function at $x_n$. Then $\langle f_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is a Cauchy sequence in ${^A}X$ that does not converge.

(Note that I am assuming that you’re restricting yourself to bounded functions, so that the uniform metric is defined.)